# Сохранение значения опции wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть опция домена (типа CDN), она используется в построении ссылки. Если опция меняется - ссылки "летят". Как сделать ее сохранение, чтобы файлы, загруженные после смены опции, меняли хост? Какие пути есть для этого?

Надо просто чтобы опция плагина использовалась и виджетом, и при построении url'а, когда файл берется из медиа библиотеки.

Comment: Надо бы переформулировать вопрос. В чем проблема?
Для работы с cdn ничего - абсолютно ничего - в WP менять не надо.

Вроде Ваш был вопрос про Autoptimize. Там есть путь cdn base url, но он нужен только этому плагину.

Comment: Свой плагин пишу. Картинки сохраняются - а cdn в настройках. Копаю в сторону добавления произвольного поля.при загрузки изображения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте относительные ссылки, например. А сам домен для построяния абсолютных ссылок храните в произвольном поле. Если я вас правильно понял